multiple connection problem with socket io in react native using @supersami/rn-foreground-servic
i track user location using @supersami/rn-foreground-servic in react native
i facing a  problem with socket, each user connecting multiple time with one device
useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io(`${mainDomain}/driverLocation`, {
      transports: ['websocket']
    });
    socket.current.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to the Socket.io server');
    });

    const info = getDeviceInfo();
    setDeviceInfo(info);
    return () => {
      socket.current.disconnect();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (permissionGranted && user?.location_tracking == 1) {
      requestForBatteryOptmine();
      startTask();
    } else {
      stopTask();
    }
  }, [permissionGranted])

  const startTask = () => {
    ReactNativeForegroundService.add_task(() => getLocation(), {
      delay: 5000,
      onLoop: true,
      taskId: 'taskid',
      onError: e => console.log('Error logging:', e),
    });

    ReactNativeForegroundService.start({
      id: 1244,
      title: 'Location service',
      message: 'Your app is running.',
      icon: 'ic_launcher',
      setOnlyAlertOnce: true,
      color: '#000000',

      importance: 'high',
      ongoing: true,
      persist: true,
    });
  };


  const emitLocationUpdateThrottled = throttle((socketIo, userId, latitude, longitude, time, phone) => {
    socketIo.emit('locationUpdate', { userId, latitude, longitude, time, phone });
  }, 1000); // Emit at most every 1000ms (1 second)

  const getLocation = async () => {
    let isConnection = true;
    NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      isConnection = state.isConnected;
    });
    console.log(" ~ file: Home.js:181 ~ getLocation ~ isConnection:", isConnection)
    console.log(" ~ file: home.js:111 ~ HomeScreen ~ getLocation ~ getLocation:", socket.current.connected,)

    if (!(socket.current?.connected)) {
      socket.current?.disconnect();
      socket.current = io(`${mainDomain}/driverLocation`, {
      
        transports: ['websocket']
      });
      socket.current.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to the Socket.io server');
      });
    }
    const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      async (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        let newLocationData = { userId: user.id, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, time: getCurrentTimeAndDate(), phone: user.mobile_no, isSync: 1 }
        emitLocationUpdateThrottled(socket.current, user.id, latitude, longitude, getCurrentTimeAndDate(), user.mobile_no);
        if (isConnection == false) {

          const storedLocationData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('offline_locaiton_data');
          if (storedLocationData) {
            const parsedStoredData = JSON.parse(storedLocationData);
            const updatedData = [...parsedStoredData, newLocationData];
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('offline_locaiton_data', JSON.stringify(updatedData));
          } else {
            const updatedData = [newLocationData];
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('offline_locaiton_data', JSON.stringify(updatedData));
          }
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(" ~ file: locationPermission.js:50 ~ watchLocation ~ error:", error)
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, // Use GPS if available
        distanceFilter: 50, // Minimum distance (in meters) between location updates
        timeout: 30000, // Maximum time (in milliseconds) to wait for a location update
        maximumAge: 60000, // M
      }
    );


    if (isConnection) {
      const storedLocationData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('offline_locaiton_data');
      if (storedLocationData && socket.current.connected) {

        const offLocation = JSON.parse(storedLocationData);
        console.log(" ~ file: Home.js:286 ~ getLocation ~ offLocation:", offLocation)
        offLocation.length > 0 && offLocation.map((loc) => {
          console.log(" ~ file: loc:", loc)
          socket.current.emit('locationUpdate', loc)
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
          AsyncStorage.removeItem('offline_locaiton_data')
        }, 3000)

      }
    }
    if (watchId) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
      }, 4000)
    }
  }



i use  this code to track location of user which is connect multiple times and emit thousand of duplicate location with same time and date.
problems
1 multiple connections.
2 single location emits multiple times with each connection
3 high load on server network in out.
